# Select All Text In a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, textview

I have searched a lot, but I still cannot find any way to do this.  I have a Fragment , which comprises of a LinearLayout. the LinearLayout has some TextView's and some nested LinearLayouts. Even the nested LinearLayouts have nothing other than TextViews. There is no other kind of View except for these two. I have made the TextViews selectable, but by this, at one time, I can only select the text of one TextView. I want to enable the user to select all text in all TextViews (in HTML, Web page style) and preferable be able to copy it to clipboard with the presented formatting. Is this possible in Android?

Edit:

I had originally considered making it a single TextView, and adding all the content inside it. However, I want to direct different parts of the text to different places (URL, phone, email, map), and while I know that this should have been possible using android:autolink="all', it didn't work as I expected and I had to separate the text into different parts in order to be able to do it. Any way this is achievable?

Answer (score 1):

Create only one text view and set the textview with HTML tags.

Simple Example,

```
   textView. setText(Html.fromHtml("<h2>Title</h2><br><p>Description here</p>"));
```

Or

Add the string in resource with HTML tags and then set the text  in code

```
 textView. setText(Html.fromHtml(yourHtmlText);
```

Note : most of the tag will be supported , not all. Example you can't set font size but can set it as small, big ..

Comment: this would have been a good idea otherwise, but the problem is, the content needs to link to different places (URL, email, map), and while I know that this should have been possible automatically using android:autolink="all", it didn't work, hence I had to make it separate TextViews. Any idea or any way this is still achievable?